# Having trouble calculating proportion of string in text mining with tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have recorded discussions from participants who were either in condition `A` or `B`.

I would like to determine the words that were repeated/shared between the two conditions.

I've unnested the data from group discussions to give the experimental condition `(A, B)` in `column1` and a single word from that condition in `column2`.

Stop_words have been removed and now I'd like to determine the proportion of shared words between the two conditions so I can eventually plot them.

Below is what I've tried. `Exp1a` is the dataframe with all the info. `Condition` is column1 with either `A` or `B` on each row.

`Word` is column2.

```
Exp1b <- Exp1a %>%
      count(Condition, word) %>%
      group_by(Condition) %>%
      mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>%
      select(-n) %>%
      spread(Condition, proportion) %>%
      gather(Condition, proportion, `A`:``B`)
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
dput(head(Exp1a,6))
structure(list(Condition = c("B", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "A"), word = c("events", 
"finance", "welfare", "attract", "purchasing", "type"), n = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name".
```

I've used a version of this before and I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this new dataframe.

I'm quite accepting if I am going at this entirely wrong, too.

Comment: Two opening ticks before `B` in last line, maybe?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? `dput`

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło Thanks for catching that. I removed the extra tick mark. The error unfortunately seems to lie in the first line still.

Comment: @CarlBoneri I added a sample of the data above.

Comment: I removed extra tick, coerced `Exp1a` to `data.frame ` with `as.data.frame` and everything runs...

Comment: @ŁukaszDeryło superb. That worked. Thanks!

Comment: So, I turn it to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove one extra tick before `B` in last line and coerce `Exp1a` to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame()`.

```
Exp1b <- Exp1a %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      count(Condition, word) %>%
      group_by(Condition) %>%
      mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>%
      select(-n) %>%
      spread(Condition, proportion) %>%
      gather(Condition, proportion, `A`:`B`)
```